# cannot change rownames of a table

Tags: r, r-rownames

I created  this table:

```
> head(table)
                  tissue1 tissue2 tissue3 tissue4 tissue5
Simple_repeat_80   58     77         48     69     115                                   131
tRNA_1              0     14         12      1      19                                     14
Simple_repeat_86    2     10          2      2      14                                       9
Simple_repeat_87    1     33         12      3      15                                      21
Simple_repeat_103   0      0          2      0       0                                       4
SINE/tRNA-Deu_20    0      0          1      0       0                                      10
```

and I put the command 
`row <- strsplit(rownames(table), "_[0-9]+")` to eliminate the underscore and the number of the elements after the name. I would to create a new table like this example:

```
> head(table)
                  tissue1 tissue2 tissue3 tissue4 tissue5
Simple_repeat   58     77         48     69     115                                   131
tRNA             0     14         12      1      19                                     14
Simple_repeat    2     10          2      2      14                                       9
Simple_repeat    1     33         12      3      15                                      21
Simple_repeat   0      0          2      0       0                                       4
SINE/tRNA-Deu    0      0          1      0       0                                      10
```

I've tried this command:

```
> row.names(table) = row
Error in `.rowNamesDF<-`(x, value = value) : 
  'row.names' duplicate non sono permesse
Inoltre: Warning message:
non-unique values when setting 'row.names': ‘DNA?’, ‘DNA/hAT-Ac’, ‘DNA/hAT-Charlie’, ‘DNA/hAT-Tag1’, ‘DNA/hAT-Tip100’, ‘DNA/MULE-MuDR’, ‘DNA/PIF-Harbinger’, ‘DNA/PiggyBac’, ‘DNA/TcMar-Mariner’, ‘DNA/TcMar-Tc1’, ‘DNA/TcMar-Tc2’, ‘DNA/TcMar-Tigger’, ‘LINE/CR1’, ‘LINE/Dong-R4’, ‘LINE/I-Jockey’, ‘LINE/L1’, ‘LINE/L2’, ‘LINE/Penelope’, ‘LINE/RTE-BovB’, ‘Low_complexity’, ‘LTR/ERV1’, ‘LTR/ERVK’, ‘LTR/ERVL’, ‘LTR/Gypsy’, ‘LTR/Gypsy?’, ‘RC/Helitron’, ‘rRNA’, ‘Satellite/acro’, ‘Simple_repeat’, ‘SINE/5S-Deu-L2’, ‘SINE/MIR’, ‘SINE/tRNA’, ‘SINE/tRNA-Deu’, ‘SINE/tRNA-RTE’, ‘snRNA’, ‘srpRNA’, ‘tRNA’
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: This can be done with `substr()`. There is a way to tell `substr()` to take the substring from the first element until the last underscore before a number. I'm not sure how though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you are trying to assign duplicate row.names, which is not legal - multiple rows would be named `Simple_repeat`. One solution is to make the names unique, for example with:

```
row.names(table) <- make.unique(row)
```

Another solution is to not make use of row names at all, but create a separate column and then use that for further processing instead of row names, e.g.

```
table$rowLabel <- row
```